# Referencing an appendix in JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I am currently developing against the FlightStats Schedules API, this is for a user to be able to search for flight schedules on a given route, on a given date.

End point looks like so

```
https://api.flightstats.com/flex/schedules/rest/v1/json/from/{departing_airport}/to/{arriving_airport}/departing/{YYYY/MM/DD}?appId=APP_ID&appKey=API_KEY&codeType=iata&extendedOptions=includeDirects
```

User will specify departing_airport, arriving_airport and date as YYYY/MM/DD

To give an example response, I'll use MEL, NRT and 2015/11/12 respectively

```
{
 "request": {
  "departureAirport": {
   "requestedCode": "mel",
   "fsCode": "MEL"
  },
  "arrivalAirport": {
   "requestedCode": "nrt",
   "fsCode": "NRT"
  },
  "codeType": {
   "requested": "iata",
   "interpreted": "IATA"
  },
  "departing": true,
  "date": {
   "year": "2015",
   "month": "11",
   "day": "12",
   "interpreted": "2015-11-12"
  },
  "url": "https://api.flightstats.com/flex/schedules/rest/v1/json/from/mel/to/nrt/departing/2015/11/12"
 },
 "scheduledFlights": [
  {
   "carrierFsCode": "JQ",
   "flightNumber": "23",
   "departureAirportFsCode": "MEL",
   "arrivalAirportFsCode": "NRT",
   "stops": 0,
   "departureTerminal": "2",
   "arrivalTerminal": "3",
   "departureTime": "2015-11-12T00:55:00.000",
   "arrivalTime": "2015-11-12T08:45:00.000",
   "flightEquipmentIataCode": "787",
   "isCodeshare": false,
   "isWetlease": false,
   "serviceType": "J",
   "serviceClasses": [
    "R",
    "F",
    "J",
    "Y"
   ],
   "trafficRestrictions": [],
   "codeshares": [
    {
     "carrierFsCode": "JL",
     "flightNumber": "5086",
     "serviceType": "J",
     "serviceClasses": [
      "Y"
     ],
     "trafficRestrictions": [],
     "referenceCode": 2088960
    }
   ],
   "referenceCode": "1492-2106903--"
  },
  {
   "carrierFsCode": "JL",
   "flightNumber": "5086",
   "departureAirportFsCode": "MEL",
   "arrivalAirportFsCode": "NRT",
   "stops": 0,
   "departureTerminal": "2",
   "arrivalTerminal": "3",
   "departureTime": "2015-11-12T00:55:00.000",
   "arrivalTime": "2015-11-12T08:45:00.000",
   "flightEquipmentIataCode": "787",
   "isCodeshare": true,
   "isWetlease": false,
   "serviceType": "J",
   "serviceClasses": [
    "Y"
   ],
   "trafficRestrictions": [],
   "operator": {
    "carrierFsCode": "JQ",
    "flightNumber": "23",
    "serviceType": "J",
    "serviceClasses": [
     "R",
     "F",
     "J",
     "Y"
    ],
    "trafficRestrictions": []
   },
   "codeshares": [],
   "referenceCode": "1492-2106903--2088960"
  }
 ],
 "appendix": {
  "airlines": [
   {
    "fs": "JL",
    "iata": "JL",
    "icao": "JAL",
    "name": "JAL",
    "active": true
   },
   {
    "fs": "JQ",
    "iata": "JQ",
    "icao": "JST",
    "name": "Jetstar",
    "active": true
   }
  ],
  "airports": [
   {
    "fs": "NRT",
    "iata": "NRT",
    "icao": "RJAA",
    "name": "Narita International Airport",
    "street1": "成田空港第2PTB(バス), Narita",
    "street2": "Chiba Prefecture",
    "city": "Tokyo",
    "cityCode": "TYO",
    "countryCode": "JP",
    "countryName": "Japan",
    "regionName": "Asia",
    "timeZoneRegionName": "Asia/Tokyo",
    "localTime": "2015-09-21T09:37:31.611",
    "utcOffsetHours": 9,
    "latitude": 35.773213,
    "longitude": 140.387443,
    "elevationFeet": 135,
    "classification": 1,
    "active": true
   },
   {
    "fs": "MEL",
    "iata": "MEL",
    "icao": "YMML",
    "name": "Tullamarine Airport",
    "city": "Melbourne",
    "cityCode": "MEL",
    "stateCode": "VIC",
    "countryCode": "AU",
    "countryName": "Australia",
    "regionName": "Oceania",
    "timeZoneRegionName": "Australia/Sydney",
    "localTime": "2015-09-21T10:37:31.611",
    "utcOffsetHours": 10,
    "latitude": -37.669611,
    "longitude": 144.849777,
    "elevationFeet": 434,
    "classification": 1,
    "active": true
   }
  ],
  "equipments": [
   {
    "iata": "787",
    "name": "Boeing 787",
    "turboProp": false,
    "jet": true,
    "widebody": true,
    "regional": false
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

My desired output at this stage would be for example
[appendix -> airline -> name] - [scheduledFlights -> carrierFsCode][scheduledFlights -> flightNumber]

Jetstar - JQ23

JAL - JL5086

So in a nutshell, to get the desired output, I need to reference the carrierFsCode against the airline name in the appendix for each result. Keep in mind that this example is (for brevity) a low traffic route. JFK to Heathrow for example is much more complex due to the number of flights on that route.

My quite incorrect PHP currently looks like this

```
$flight_json=get_flight_stats($from,$to,$date);
$flight_stats=$flight_json['scheduledFlights'];
$airlines=$flight_json['appendix']['airlines'];

foreach($flight_stats as $flight_stat)
{
    echo $flight_stat['carrierFsCode'].$flight_stat['flightNumber']."<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}
foreach($airlines as $airline)
{
    echo $airline['name']."<br>";
}
```

Which returns

JQ23

JL5086

Jetstar

JAL

The get_flight_stats function is used for creating the end point URL, get_file_contents, json_decode then array_map return.

Apologies if this has been asked, just haven't been able to find the right search term and am finding myself a bit stuck.

(EDIT)
Thanks to @jolyonruss, my final code is as follows:

```
foreach($flight_stats as $flight_stat)
{
    /* store the fsCode for this flight */
    $fsCode = $flight_stat['carrierFsCode'];

    foreach($airlines as $airline)
    {
        /* test to see if the airline's fsCode matches the flight */
        if($airline['fs'] === $fsCode)
        {
            echo $airline['name']." - ".$fsCode.$flight_stat['flightNumber']."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Worked a treat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to nest your for loops, something like this:

```
$flight_json=get_flight_stats($from,$to,$date);
$flight_stats=$flight_json['scheduledFlights'];
$airlines=$flight_json['appendix']['airlines'];

foreach($flight_stats as $flight_stat)
{
    echo $flight_stat['carrierFsCode'].$flight_stat['flightNumber']."<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    /* store the fsCode for this flight */
    $fsCode = $flight_stat['carrierFsCode'];

    foreach($airlines as $airline)
    {
        /* test to see if the airline's fsCode matches the flight */
        if($airline['fs'] === $fsCode) 
        {
            echo $airline['name']."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

This is pseudo code, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for that, definitely got me on the right track. I have a serious knowledge hole when it comes to arrays, so thanks for your help.


For anyone else who comes across this my final code is in my edit